# Azure iot edge / built-in metrics / proxy

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I need to send the build-in metrics of IoT edge from "the metrics collector module" in the gateway to "Log analytics" in the Cloud
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-collect-and-transport-metrics

there's a proxy between edge and Azure

with the UploadTarget=IoTMessage it is possible to go through the proxy with the telemetry messages : metrics collector->edgehub->PROXY->iothub->function->log analytics

BUT

Is it possible to send through a proxy with the configuration UploadTarget=AzureMonitor ?
metrics collector->PROXY->log analytics

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the documentation you linked. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-edge/how-to-collect-and-transport-metrics?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=iothub#proxy-considerations

Comment: Thank you @VenkatYalla ; does it mean we need to configure the proxy url under IoTEdgeMetricsCollector' environment variables ?

Go to "IoT hub" then  "IoT Edge" .
Select my edge device . 
Go to "set Modules". 
Select my Metrics Collector. 
Go to "Environment Variables". 
Add a variable with the NAME "https_proxy". 
  
Is it Correct ?